# ILMerge error: "try to set ILMergeDebugInfo to false"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, dll, ilmerge

I'm using Winforms to make an exe that can open a web page. The following are the dependencies I use:

[image]

Then I introduced ILMerge and MSBuild.ILMerge.Task, and then regenerated the project in order to merge these dependencies into the exe, but the following error occurred

> Possible reason: some of the merge assemblies have portable PDBs. Try
> to set lLMergeDebuginfo to false.
>
> ILMerge.Merge: There were errors reported in CefSharp.Core.Runtime's
> metadata. Unsupported PDB deleted bitset is not empty.

[image]

What's happening and how to fix this issue? Or is there any other more reliable way to merge dll into exe?

Comment: CefSharp needs a bunch of  unmanaged dlls to get its job done.  They can't be merged, so there is very little point in trying to merge at all.  Universal one-file deployment is a setup.exe installer, that's no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CefSharp relies on a bunch of unmanaged dlls to get its job done.

They can't be merged, so there is very little point in trying to merge at all.

Universal one-file deployment is a setup.exe installer, that's no problem.